# Extracting a range of values from a list, but excluding a few in R

Tags: r, vector, extract

If I have a vector with the integers from 1 to 100 and I want to extract the integers from 30 to 60 but not include 40 how do I do that?
I can do each part on its own:

```
y<-1:100
y[30:60]
y[-40]
```

But I can't find a way to do both at once. How do I do that?

Note that I am NOT looking for a solution like this:

```
y[c(30:39,41:60)]
```

but instead, a solution that explicitly extracts the value I don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another base R option using `%in%` and `&`

```
y[(u <- seq_along(y)) %in% 30:60 & u != 40]
```

Answer (score 2):

An option is `setdiff`

```
y[setdiff(30:60, 40)]
```

It can also be a vector of values

```
y[setdiff(30:60, c(40, 47, 51))]
```